# How many concurrent users can Agora RTC SDK support at the same time?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, agora.io

I used both the native and web version of the Agora RTC SDK.  I am wondering what's the maximum number of concurrent users.  Also, are there any difference of the number in setting up Communication mode vs LiveStreaming mode?

Answer (score 0):

Agora says that it recommends that the number not exceed 17 users. If there are more than 17 users sending streams at the same time then each one of them will see exactly 17 ones and those 17 differs from user to another because they are chosen randomly.
For a more specific and accurate answer you can refer to this link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).